# Attr value doesn't work after editing text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have text input and navigation items. Text input is being filled with .attr("value", xxx) with value based on clicked item. It works well, but after I type something manually in text field, later .attr methods don't work.

Html:

```
<label class="editor-small-label" for="editor-website">Website www:</label><br>
  <input id="editor-website" class="text-input" name="editor-website" type="text">

<label class="editor-small-label" for="editor-facebook">Facebook link:</label><br>
  <input id="editor-facebook" class="text-input" name="editor-facebook" type="text">
```

On icon click:

```
$('#editor-facebook').attr('value', data[icon_id].facebook);
$('#editor-website').attr('value', data[icon_id].website);
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Please provide more details to your question. Code would help.

Comment: I have added some code, but there is really nothing special about it, yet problem occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *value attribute* is only used by browser to set initial *value property* on the element.

After page load ( or insertion into dom) the attribute is useless and does not change the same way the property does

Use `val()` instead to set the *value property*

```
$('#editor-facebook').val( data[icon_id].facebook);
$('#editor-website').val( data[icon_id].website);
```